# How to change the Background Color of Button

Tags: silverlight

No matter what I change the Background property to in a button it hardly changes, what am I supposed to do if I want a completely different colored button?

I know I can do this via editing a template of a button, but this seems like overkill.

Comment: You shall accept an answer among the three you have here so that other SO users could benefit from the your experience as I did, though I had to read through all of the answers since no one was marked. Thanks for your question anyway, this just helped me work out a solution for my project. =)

Answer (score 3):

This looks like an issue with SilverLight 2.0 and the default ContentTemplate for a Button.  I took a look at the source:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:Button"> 
<Grid>
    <!-- snipped the 36 lines of VisualStatManager here -->
    <Border x:Name="Background" CornerRadius="3" Background="White" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"  Margin="1"> 
            <Border Opacity="0"  x:Name="BackgroundAnimation" Background="#FF448DCA" />
            <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundGradient" >
                <Rectangle.Fill> 
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint=".7,0" EndPoint=".7,1">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#F9FFFFFF" Offset="0.375" /> 
                        <GradientStop Color="#E5FFFFFF" Offset="0.625" /> 
                        <GradientStop Color="#C6FFFFFF" Offset="1" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush> 
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
        </Grid> 
    </Border>
    <ContentPresenter
            x:Name="contentPresenter" 
            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" 
            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
            Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="DisabledVisualElement" RadiusX="3" RadiusY="3" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Opacity="0" IsHitTestVisible="false" /> 
    <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2" Margin="1" Stroke="#FF6DBDD1" StrokeThickness="1" Opacity="0" IsHitTestVisible="false" />
</Grid>
```

The issue is the Rectangle with it's own Background is on top of the Grid which has the Background you've set. (Also, the Border is hard-coded to White).  We can fix this using our own ContentTemplate, but that means also adding all the VisualStatManager stuff to get all the animations that go along with the Button.

A second method is to subclass Button, and modify the template in the OnApplyTemplate override.  Here is an example that lowers the opacity of the stock Button so the background shows through:

```
public class BKButton : Button {

public override void OnApplyTemplate() {
    base.OnApplyTemplate();

    Border border = GetTemplateChild("Background") as Border;
    Rectangle rect = GetTemplateChild("BackgroundGradient") as Rectangle;

    if(border != null) {
        border.Background = this.Background;
        border.Opacity = .6;
    }
    if (rect != null) {
        LinearGradientBrush lbrush = rect.Fill as LinearGradientBrush;
        if (lbrush != null) {
            lbrush.Opacity = .6;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ViNull, your solution worked perfect! Now I am able to change backgroud color of button. The only issue I am facing now is the color doesnt change until mouse is removed from button. I want to change the color even when mouse hovers over button. Could you provide workaround for this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to override the mouse states of the VisualStateManager - if you need more custom changes that just tweaking the background, it's worth it to just go ahead and provide your own ControlTemplate

Answer (score 2):

I am not quite sure what do you mean by "button hardly changes" but when I write `<Button x:Name="button" Background="Gold" Foreground="Red" Content="Hello!" />` I get a golden button with red text. If you want to edit the button even more (change how it looks when you click on it etc.) then you still have to use templates and visual state manager. I found two pretty good tutorials that specifically concentrate on the visual aspects of a Silverlight button: http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/03/creating_a_custom_skin_for_sil.html and http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2008/11/23/using-the-visual-state-manager-in-silverlight-templates.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. But I did workaround. Instead of changing button background color, I set the border width of button to 100, and then set the color for border, for example gray.

So you will have gray button. I know this is not good way, but it worked for me.
Hope it helps

Here is code example:

```
    Dim btn As New Button
    btn.Width = 75
    btn.Height = 35
    btn.BorderThickness = New Thickness(0, 0, 0, 100)
    btn.BorderBrush = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray)
    AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf btn_Click
    AddHandler btn.MouseEnter, AddressOf btn_MouseEnter
    AddHandler btn.MouseLeave, AddressOf btn_MouseLeave

    LayoutRoot.Children.Add(btn)


Private Sub btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    MessageBox.Show("pressed")
End Sub
Private Sub btn_MouseEnter(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    DirectCast(sender, Button).BorderBrush = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray)
End Sub
Private Sub btn_MouseLeave(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    DirectCast(sender, Button).BorderBrush = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray)
End Sub
```